# Dash Callback if no option selected

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have created a callback function to return a filtered data table if an option is selected.

```
    # call back to update overview player table
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='player_table', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='select_list', component_property='value')]

)

def display_player_table(list_selected):
    dff_player = df_player[df_player.band==list_selected]
    dff_player.drop(columns=['band',], inplace=True)

    return [
        dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dff_player.columns],
        data=dff_player.to_dict('records'),
        style_header=
        # {'display': 'none'},
        {
            'backgroundColor': 'white',
            'fontWeight': 'bold',
            'color': 'black',
            'border': '0px',
            'font_family': 'Roboto',
            'font_size' : '18px',
            'whiteSpace': 'normal',
        },
        style_cell={'border': '0px', 'textAlign': 'left', 'font_family': 'Roboto', 'fontWeight': '60', 'font_size' : '15px', 'line_height': '40px', 'width':'60px'},
        style_cell_conditional=[
        {
        'if': {'column_id': c},
            'font_size': '11px'
        } for c in ['Current Team']
        ],

        style_as_list_view=True,
        page_action='native',
        fixed_rows={'headers':True},
        style_table={'height': '700px', 'overflowY': 'auto'},
    )]
```

I  have tried a number of different ways (if / else statements) but can't find a way to show the full df if no option is selected. What is the best way to do return an unfiltered table if no option is selected?

I am using Python and Dash-Plotly

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
if not list_selected:
    dff_player = df_player
else:
    dff_player = df_player[df_player.band==list_selected]
```

Also I am unsure where df_player is coming from, is is defined as a global?

Comment: I have, just re tried and it is coming up with an error

Comment: the dataframe is defined an pulled from a csv above `df_player = pd.read_excel(DATA_PATH.joinpath('Player_Profile.xlsx'))` but I haven't made it global (not 100% sure how to do this). Based on the error I think the issue is coming from the else and if statement trying to redefine the already filter df. If that makes sense. How can I have the df_player global?

Comment: what does the error look like? Have you checked how list_selected looks like when nothing is selected? Is 'select-list'  a dcc.checklist?

Comment: sorry for all the messages..... it is because I dropped the band column within the statements, but that is what I was filtering by. However, ideally I want to filter by band but not show it in the final df. Is there a way round this?

Comment: it looks to me like you're dropping band after you filter, is it not the extra ',' thats messing it up? EDIT: the ',' after band in the drop line

Comment: No, removed and also taken out the naming of the df to before the else and if statements and not working. Also tried naming the df differently, my only assumption is that its not picking up the original df and is picking up the df displaying which already has 'band' dropped

Comment: this is the error `File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5130, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'band'`